My chrome browser doesn't show up as a device in flutter
I am currently developing a website using Flutter, and Google Chrome was showing me as an option and it was working well about two months ago. I stopped working on the website and now I have returned to add some features, but I cannot run the project on Chrome. Since the Chrome option is no longer available! I use a Mac M1.
enter image description here

here flutter doctor -v

[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.2, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-SA)
    • Flutter version 3.19.2 on channel stable at /Users/mhmdalnzy/flutter
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.2.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/mhmdalnzy/flutter. Consider adding
      /Users/mhmdalnzy/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7482962148 (9 weeks ago), 2024-02-27 16:51:22 -0500
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however
      it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and
      upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mhmdalnzy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.88.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.119
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for MM. Ensure the device is
      unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
      network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code
      -27)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I have used several methods but it did not work

try flutter config --enable-web

Please run this command to solve this error.
to open your shell configuration file
nano ~/.bash_profile

Add this line at the end of the file and save the file:
Add the following line at the end of the file:

source ~/.bash_profile

run this command then after run flutter doctor -v command to check remove this warning.
